# How to read pandas CSV file with comma separator and comma thousand separator

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with rows that looks like this:
**87.89,"2,392.05",14.77,373.2** ( third row has coma thousand separator)

pandas keeps considering the comma in second column as a row separator and showing "Error tokenizing data" Error.

is there a away in pandas to ignore comas between double quotes?
thanks

sample rows :

```
9999992613813558569,87.89,"2,392.05",14.77,373.2
9999987064038821584,95.11,"3,397.04",42.15,"1,461.14"
9999956300203713283,6.67,194.02,41.23,"1,105.45"
9999946809576027532,15.08,353.84,29.43,591.9
```

**Edit:**

i already tried :

```
read_csv(file, quotechar='"', encoding='latin1', thousands=',')
read_csv(file, quotechar='"', encoding='latin1', escapechar ='"')
```

Comment: well when i do `read_csv()` on your data it ignores comas between double quotes.. why its not working for you!

Comment: @AbdullahAhmedGhaznavi what arguments are you using?

Comment: without any argument i m just doing `pd.read_csv('sample.csv')`

Comment: @AbdullahAhmedGhaznavi i tried it on the lines above and it worked fine. but for some reason , pandas is unable to process the whole file.

Comment: Then check your data it seems like on some row you have more columns then other! or it maybe possible that on some row there were not `" "` marks check your data properly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reading it with:

```
pd.read_csv(myfile, encoding='latin1', quotechar='"')
```

Each column that contains these will be treated as type `object`.
Once you get this, to get back to float use:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x.astype(str).str.replace(',',''), errors='coerce'))
```

Alternatively you can try:

```
pd.read_csv(myfile, encoding='latin1', quotechar='"', error_bad_lines=False)
```

Here you can see what was omitted from original `csv` - what caused the problem.

For each line that was omitted you'll receive a `Warning` instead of `Error`.

Comment: I tried this before, it didn't work, i also tried thousands=","

Comment: What's your pandas version?

Comment: @MoayyadYaghi Could you edit your question with code examples of what you tried

Comment: @zipa pandas version: 0.22.0 python 3.6

Comment: @MoayyadYaghi Have you tried it like edit - without `escapechar` and `thousands`

Comment: @MoayyadYaghi Can you share an example of data, couple of more rows.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
pd.read_csv(myfile, encoding='latin1', quotechar='"', thousands=',')
```